# Why Jupyter Notebook Online Can't Read an Excel file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load an excel file online.
This this my path directory.
C:\Users\Don.A.Charles\Downloads\Practice\sorted_data.xlsx

However, I am trying to load the file through Jupyter Notebook Online with no success
https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/

Can anyone suggest anything to amend the code to allow the program to load the data?
This is the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Don.A.Charles\Downloads\Practice\sorted_data.xlsx")
```

I am receiving the error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Don.A.Charles\Downloads\Practice\sorted_data.xlsx'

Comment: The server which runs the Jupyter Notebook Online has no access to your computer where the file is stored.

Comment: You need to load the file to Jupyter file system instead of reading from local drive.

Comment: Ok, so how do I load the file to the Jupyter online system?

Comment: There is an "Upload Files" button, upper-left.

Comment: I upload it from the button from the upper left. I typed the code with no success
     df=pd.read_excel("sorted_data.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

You can not access local files from an online server like that.

You will need to upload the file to some storage that is accessible in https://jupyter.org/ or some external place (Google Drive/Drop box etc.) from where you can load it through http.

Sadly do not have enough experience with jupyter.org it self to know are they supporting file upload.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little daunting, but you'll have more flexibility if you run Jupyter locally, on your own machine.

The easiest way to do this is probably to [install Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution). Then open an Anaconda prompt from the *Start* menu. Use the `cd` command to change directories to your project directory (e.g. a `python_projects` folder in your home directory, call it what you like). Then type `jupyter notebook` and now you're running locally. Then you can load the file with the command you were using before.

Comment: Some form of [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) may be easier. The install `conda install notebook` then installs everything necessary. Opening a notebook is then just `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I have Anaconda and Jupyter on my computer at home. But I don't have it at work. So I was trying to run Jupyter online. Thanks for the assistance anyway.